# Facebook Conversions API - Invalid Timestamp errors

Tags: facebook, facebook-business-manager, conversions-api

I am receiving a handful of errors regarding the event timestamp. I have confirmed that I am sending a UNIX timestamp in seconds. This is what I have implemented in the front-end of our code to get the UNIX timestamp in seconds: `Math.round(Date.now() / 1000)`
Also, it looks like less then 1% of the events are affected for each event created, so that's why I'm a bit confused and not sure how to resolve these errors.

Error message:

> The timestamp for the InitiateCheckout events sent from your server is in the future. Timestamps are metadata sent alongside each event you send from your server and they represent the time of day when an event actually occurred. For example: the time that a customer made a purchase on your website. All timestamps should represent a point in time that occurred within the last 7 days"

[Click here to see a screenshot of the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFhOJ.png)

Has anyone encountered these type of errors? If so, any advice on how to resolve them?
I am not sure how to go about this

Comment: Local time on clients might just be slightly off?